# Creating a complex template?

Tags: qt, qml

I want to create a type of slideshow in which the user can hit enter to get the details of that particular item, which are organized in another slideshow.

So, my crude template would be something like this:

```
Item {
    property string label
    property string icon

    width: 500
    height: 500

    Text {
        text: label
        anchors.left: parent.left
    }

    Image {
        source: icon
        anchors.right: parent.right
    }

    ContentPlaceholder {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

        AnotherContentPlaceholder {

            PageIndicator {
                count: AnotherContentPlaceholder.children
            }
        }
    }

    PageIndicator {
        count: ContentPlaceholder.children
    }
}
```

Then, my crude object would be something like this:

```
MyTemplate {
    label: "Hello World"
    icon: "images/myIcon"

    MyContent {
        Rectangle {
            width: 100
            height: 100
            color: "red"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }

        Text {
            text: "My Item 1 Text"
        }

        MyInnerContent {
            Rectangle {
                width: 100
                height: 100
                color: "purple"
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }

            Text {
                text: "My Sub-Item 1-A Text"
            }
        }

        MyInnerContent {
            Rectangle {
                width: 100
                height: 100
                color: "brown"
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }

            Text {
                text: "My Sub-Item 1-B Text"
            }
        }
    }

    MyContent {
        Rectangle {
            width: 100
            height: 100
            color: "green"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }

        Text {
            text: "My Item 2 Text"
        }

        MyInnerContent {
            Rectangle {
                width: 100
                height: 100
                color: "yellow"
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }

            Text {
                text: "My Sub-Item 2-A Text"
            }
        }

        MyInnerContent {
            Rectangle {
                width: 100
                height: 100
                color: "orange"
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }

            Text {
                text: "My Sub-Item 2-B Text"
            }
        }
    }

    MyContent {
        Rectangle {
            width: 100
            height: 100
            color: "pink"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }

        Text {
            text: "My Item 3 Text"
        }

        MyInnerContent {
            Rectangle {
                width: 100
                height: 100
                color: "maroon"
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }

            Text {
                text: "My Sub-Item 3-A Text"
            }
        }

        MyInnerContent {
            Rectangle {
                width: 100
                height: 100
                color: "turquoise"
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }

            Text {
                text: "My Sub-Item 3-B Text"
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Are complicated templates like this possible? How would one go about creating them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this behavior using  the `ObjectModel` type

```
 import QtQuick 2.0
  import QtQml.Models 2.1

  Rectangle {
      ObjectModel {
          id: itemModel
          Rectangle { height: 30; width: 80; color: "red" }
          Rectangle { height: 30; width: 80; color: "green" }
          Rectangle { height: 30; width: 80; color: "blue" }
      }

      ListView {
          anchors.fill: parent
          model: itemModel
      }
  }
```

Simply create a property in your crude template (MyTemplate.qml)  that has a VisualItemModel that reads from the property  'myModel'  like this:

```
Item {
    property string label
    property string icon
    property var  myModel

    // use a GridView or ListView to display the model
    // ** EDIT **
    ListView {
       model: myModel
    }
}
```

and finally,

```
  MyContent {
      myModel: ObjectModel {
            Item { } // example
            Rect { } // example
            // your content 


      }
  }
```

Comment: Changed  VisualItemModel to  ListView as you have to display the ObjectModel in a ListView